# Wikitude on Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, augmented-reality, wikitude

I'm trying Wikitude on Phonegap, but can't load plugin.

Error log is below. This error is on sample on GitHub(https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap/tree/master/iOS/SampleProjects/Basic).

```
2013-06-20 11:26:20.444 kitamaecat[3056:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-06-20 11:26:20.855 kitamaecat[3056:907] Resetting plugins due to page load.

2013-06-20 11:26:21.496 kitamaecat[3056:907] DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ?ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release. 

2013-06-20 11:26:21.663 kitamaecat[3056:907] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/ACFECDB8-5DFC-4C7E-86AD-F08EFC09E94C/kitamaecat.app/www/index.html

2013-06-20 11:33:55.314 kitamaecat[3056:907] Received Event: deviceready

2013-06-20 11:33:57.590 kitamaecat[3056:907] Wikitude Plugin not loaded. You first have to call load and then show.
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that you pressed the wrong button. Try the one in the middle of the screen. 
You can also have a look at the sample code to figure out what you did wrong.